# Regular expression for characters after '.'

Tags: c#, regex

I need to detect following format when I enter serial number like

```
CK123456.789
```

I used Regex with pattern of

```
^(CV[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}
```

to match but if I enter

```
CK123456.7890
```

it still able to proceed without flagging error. Is there a better regular expression to detect the trailing 3 digits after '.'?

Comment: `^(CK\d*)\.\d*`. Change `*` to `+` or keep it, or change it to an indicator for amount of characters, depending what you need.

Comment: `\d` also matches other characters, so be careful if you change to that.

Comment: Why use regex, just search for the '.' and check if next symbols are numbers and >=3

Comment: I hope you noticed the difference between `CK` and `CV` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use the regular expression matcher, you might need to enclose it in `^...$` which forces the pattern to be the *whole* string, i.e.

`^CK[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3}$` (Note the CK prefix).

I've also removed your leading (mismatched) parenthesis.

Comment: I have used your suggested method but still not working

Comment: Hum. It should do. Try `^(CV[0-9]{6}\.[0-9]{3})$`

Comment: Did you want to match CV, CK, or both?

Comment: sorry i meant CK. Ultimately the system should flag an error if I enter CK123456.7890

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer.

Comment: great! it is working now..thanks alot